# Can you help me to automate this?

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-slider

I have the following bit of jQuery that is running a slider. I'd like it to start automatically and pause on hover.

Here it is in testing: (This is not my code by the way it is from a template)

http://webcontentmanager.co.uk/clients/alex/testing-2.html

The jquery which runs this slider is as follows:

```
/*!Full-width scroller*/
$(".fullwidth-slider li").not(".text-on-img .fullwidth-slider li").each(function() {
var $_this = $(this),
    this_img = $_this.find("img").width();
$_this.css({"width": this_img + 20});
$(".fs-entry-content", $_this).css("opacity", "1");
$( $_this).css("opacity", "1")
});
$(".fullwidth-slider").each(function() {
var $this = $(this),
    $this_par = $(this).parent(),
    $this_img = $this.find("img").attr("height"),
    $this_top = $this.position().top,
    scroller = $this.theSlider({
        mode: "scroller"
    }).data("theSlider");
$(".prev, .next", $this_par).css({
    height: $this_img
});
$(".related-projects .prev, .related-projects .next").css({
    top: $this_top + "px"
});
$(".prev i", $this_par).click(function() {
    if (!scroller.noSlide) scroller.slidePrev();
});
$(".next i", $this_par).click(function() {
    if (!scroller.noSlide) scroller.slideNext();
});


scroller.ev.on("updateNav sliderReady", function() {
    if (scroller.lockRight) {
        $(".next", $this_par).addClass("disabled");
    }
    else {
        $(".next", $this_par).removeClass("disabled");
    };

    if (scroller.lockLeft) {
        $(".prev", $this_par).addClass("disabled");
    }
    else {
        $(".prev", $this_par).removeClass("disabled");
    };
    });

});
```

Comment: Why would you edit my comments? Makes no sense to alter the post for no reason. You took out my please and thank you's which I was taught was polite...

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or a link to a page where we can see this running, please.

Comment: You can not send jsfiddle to understand what's going on?

Comment: Err it is on a local test server to be honest. I will try and put something up online, bare with me.

Comment: @JackZelig I have updated this question and provided a test page where I have pasted the template code. The jQuery provided is that which runs this slider. Are you able to help me automate it?

Comment: You only have a limited number of slides and your slider doesn't loop. What should happen when the last slide is reached?

Comment: @JackZelig - Well the client would like it to just loop round again from the start. He'd like it to move one photo at a time, as it does when you click the button. Is this possible. I've played with jQuery plugins before but my attempts have failed to automate it. He'd also like it to pause on hover. Thanks kindly

Comment: @JackZelig - I should mention that is the correct width for the slider. lol I just ripped that bit of code out of the content area to make a test.

Comment: The link you provided is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To get you going in the right direction, you can do this to make the slider scroll automatically:

```
var i = setInterval(function(){
  jQuery("div.next i").trigger("click");
}, 500);
```

On hover you can then use: `clearInterval(i)`

I'm not sure about the looping functionality. Your demo page contains masses of JavaScript and CSS includes which are not relevant to the problem.

It's not immediately obvious where the relevant JS lies.

If you can make a fiddle with a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) I can help you more.

Comment: Yeah like I say I just ripped content from a page and saved it. The JS itself is in a file called main.js which is exactly as it is above.

Comment: I fear that you're missing the point :) Make a JS fiddle, minimize the amount of code (strip out what's irrelevant) and don't make me fight through loads of irrelevant dependencies to get to the problem.

Comment: Okay Jack, I understand. I will try and strip this back. Thanks for your help so far. :-)